# Java partition method

Tags: java, partitioning

I'm trying to create a partition function that accepts three parameters: a text string, a pattern string, and an integer k.

The goal is to store the contents of the pattern of length m in a string array of k+1 fragments, where each fragment is of length m/k+1 (or as close to).
For instance if the string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"  is parsed to the method where k = 2
The array should look something like this [ABCDEFGHI, JKLMNOPQ, RSTUVWXYZ]

The program runs fine when m/k+1 is divided evenly, however when result produces a remainder  the results are off. I’ve noticed that the errors seems to correspond with the remainder of m/k+1

This is the part of the code I'm having problems with:

```
public static String[] partition(String text, String pattern, int k) {

    String[] fragment = new String[k+1];
    int f = k+1;
    int m = pattern.length();
    int fragmentSize = (int)Math.floor(m/f);
    int lastCharIndex;

    // cannot partition evenly{
        int i = 0;
        while(i < f) {
            // set the first partition as the largest
            if(fragment[i] == fragment[0]) {
                fragmentSize = (int)Math.ceil(m/f);
                lastCharIndex = i * fragmentSize;
                fragment[i] = pattern.substring(lastCharIndex, lastCharIndex+fragmentSize);
            }
            else {
                fragmentSize = (int)Math.floor(m/f);
                lastCharIndex = i * fragmentSize;
                fragment[i] = pattern.substring(lastCharIndex, lastCharIndex+fragmentSize);
            }
            i++;

        }

    return fragment;
```

Using the example above the output I’m currently receiving is [ABCDEFGHI, IJKLMNOP, QRSTUVWX]

I have a feeling it has something to do with the explicit cast of fragmentSize, but I can't figure out  a way around it.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. Let's say you have 26 letters, and want 3 fragments. That makes a first fragment of 9 elements, a second of 9 elements, and a last one of 8 elements.

Your logic makes each fragments of length 8 (`floor(26 / 3)`), except the first one, which is of length 9 (`ceil(26 / 3)`). Not only that, but you add the additional letter of the first fragment to the second one.

Side note: the test `if(fragment[i] == fragment[0])` should in fact be `if (i == 0)`. And you should make your numbers double to avoid losing the decimal part.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to figure it out with your advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

All your operations are made with `int`, which means two things :

- they also produce int, and you loose the decimal part
- your calls to `Math.ceil`and `Math.floor` are useless : they need a double as argument but already get an int (as you pass the result of an operation involving only int), there is no floor or ceil to be made.

You should start use `double` when declaring  `f` and `m`  :

```
double f = (double) k+1;
double m = (double) pattern.length();
```